# Receive transaction data ethereum error TypeError: <lambda>

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

I am trying to get the hash and the data of the transactions after doing them in python with web3. I have the following code:

```
nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account)
tx = {
    'nonce' : nonce,
    'gas' : 5000000,
    'gasPrice' : web3.toWei(50,'gwei'),
    'chainId': 3
}
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)
tx_hash = contract.functions.savetr(Addressmapping,Coordenadas,imh,Url).buildTransaction(tx)
signed_tx = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx_hash, private_key)
web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
tx_receipt = web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(signed_tx)
print(tx_receipt)
```

the transaction works fine and completes successfully, but extracting the data with "signed_tx" throws this error:

```
    raceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\aaa\Proyectos\mil\definitivos\div.py", line 197, in <module>
    enviar_transaccion_datos(web3, private_key, contract, Coordenadas, Url, Imagen, Addressmapping, tx, tx_receipt)
  File "c:\Users\aaa\Proyectos\mil\definitivos\div.py", line 72, in enviar_transaccion_datos
    tx_receipt = web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(signed_tx)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\decorators.py", line 51, in wrapper
    return to_wrap(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 526, in waitForTransactionReceipt
    return self.wait_for_transaction_receipt(transaction_hash, timeout, poll_latency)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 532, in wait_for_transaction_receipt
    return wait_for_transaction_receipt(self.web3, transaction_hash, timeout, poll_latency)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\transactions.py", line 105, in wait_for_transaction_receipt        
    txn_receipt = web3.eth.get_transaction_receipt(txn_hash)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\module.py", line 53, in caller
    (method_str, params), response_formatters = method.process_params(module, *args, **kwargs)  # noqa: E501
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\method.py", line 201, in process_params
    _apply_request_formatters(params, self.request_formatters(method)))
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\functional.py", line 45, in inner
    return callback(fn(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\method.py", line 51, in _apply_request_formatters
    formatted_params = pipe(params, request_formatters)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 667, in cytoolz.functoolz.pipe
    return c_pipe(data, funcs)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 642, in cytoolz.functoolz.c_pipe
    data = func(data)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 254, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
    raise
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\abi.py", line 799, in map_abi_data
    return pipe(data, *pipeline)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 667, in cytoolz.functoolz.pipe
    return c_pipe(data, funcs)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 642, in cytoolz.functoolz.c_pipe
    data = func(data)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 254, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
    raise
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\abi.py", line 833, in data_tree_map
    return recursive_map(map_to_typed_data, data_tree)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\decorators.py", line 30, in wrapped
    wrapped_val = to_wrap(*args)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\formatters.py", line 89, in recursive_map
    items_mapped = map_collection(recurse, data)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\formatters.py", line 76, in map_collection
    return datatype(map(func, collection))
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\formatters.py", line 88, in recurse
    return recursive_map(func, item)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\decorators.py", line 30, in wrapped
    wrapped_val = to_wrap(*args)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\formatters.py", line 89, in recursive_map
    items_mapped = map_collection(recurse, data)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\formatters.py", line 76, in map_collection
    return datatype(map(func, collection))
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\abi.py", line 855, in __new__
    return super().__new__(cls, *iterable)
    return recursive_map(func, item)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\decorators.py", line 30, in wrapped
    wrapped_val = to_wrap(*args)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\formatters.py", line 89, in recursive_map
    items_mapped = map_collection(recurse, data)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\formatters.py", line 76, in map_collection
    return datatype(map(func, collection))
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'hash', 'r', 's', and 'v'
```

I tried to pass the variable to a dictionary and other methods but nothing, why is this?
thank you so much!!

Comment: What's the traceback of the error?

Answer (score 1):

```
     import web3


     tx = { 
       'nonce': nonce, 
        'to': YOUR_ADD,
       'value': web3.toWei(0.01, 'ether'),
       'gas': 21000,
        'gasPrice' : web3.toWei(60, 'gwei'),
      }
       
     

     signed_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, PRIVATE_KEY) 
     tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
     print( "TX hash:" , web3.toHex(tx_hash))
```

Does this work for you?